# How to speed up backtracking algorithm?

Tags: c++, backtracking, recursive-backtracking

A problem I was given requires us to solve using a backtracking style algorithm. I wrote one based upon a given solution to a similar problem, but I need it to be faster (run all test cases in under 3 seconds.)

The problem statement is as follows:

Given two numbers n and k, determine the number of ways one can put k bishops
on an n × n chessboard so that no two of them are in attacking positions.

The input file may contain multiple test cases. Each test case occupies a single line in
the input file and contains two integers n(1 ≤ n ≤ 8) and k(0 ≤ k ≤ n2).
A test case containing two zeros terminates the input.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

#define MAXN 8

long long solution_count;

void construct_candidates (int bishops [], int c, int n, int candidates [],
    int * ncandidates)
{
    bool legal_move;

    int start = 0;
    if (c)
        start = bishops [c-1];

    * ncandidates = 0;
    for (int p = start; p <n * n; p ++)
    {
        legal_move = true;

        for (int j = 0; j <c; j ++)
            if (abs (bishops [j]/n-p/n) ==
                abs (bishops [j]% n-p% n))
            {
                legal_move = false;
                break;
            }

        if (legal_move == true)
            candidates [(* ncandidates) ++] = p;
    }
}

void backtracking (int bishops [], int c, int n, int k)
{
    if (c == k)
        solution_count ++;
    else
    {
        int ncandidates;
        int candidates [MAXN * MAXN];

        construct_candidates (bishops, c, n, candidates, & ncandidates);

        for (int i = 0; i <ncandidates; i ++)
        {
            bishops [c] = candidates [i];
            backtracking (bishops, c + 1, n, k);
        }
    }
}

long long little_bishops_by_backtracking (int n, int k)
{
    int bishops [2 * (MAXN-1) + 1];

    solution_count = 0;
    backtracking (bishops, 0, n, k);

    return solution_count;
}

int main (int ac, char * av [])
{
    int n, k;

    while (cin >> n >> k, n || k)
        cout << little_bishops_by_backtracking (n, k) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me try to speed this up? Is there a better way to eliminate more candidate solutions faster?

Comment: If you got a TLE (Time Limit Exceeded) wih an oherwise correct solution, then it often is necessary to change the approach. Speed optimisation is unlikely to make sure that the execution is sufficiently faster, this is the purpose of time limits, they never check for speed optimisation, they check for the correct approach. Avoid simulating things, look for math solutions instead.

Comment: Did you by the way compare with solutions for the N Queens problem?

Comment: I based this off a backtracking solution to the N-Queens problem. And I am not allowed to use a math/combinatorics approach. I must get accepted verdict with a backtracking algorithm, but so far I’m not seeing a way to do that within the time limit.